# GTFS editor, using PBABase , compile error regarding em() entity manager

Tags: java, playframework, gtfs

I am trying to run [gtfs-editor](https://github.com/conveyal/gtfs-editor).

I get compile errors for all the uses of em() for all the entity handling classes. I have a working gis db and I have got past a previous error of failing to connect, so I think I am in.

I have to say though if this is because it cant get hold of a db it's got a funny way of saying so.
Is this a classic problem with other entity handlers if the user hasnt installed properly.

Here's the error message and line:

> Error raised is : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method em() from the type JPABase 
>   /app/jobs/ProcessGtfsSnapshotMerge.java line 398

```
Trip.em().createNativeQuery("UPDATE trip SET pattern_id = ? WHERE id = ?").setParameter(1, patternId).setParameter(2,  tripId).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: My problem was not having the exact version of Play needed was 1.2.5, anything else doesnt work. I tried to come back here with how come there is a class level static version of em() when and only you have 1.2.5, but failed ;).